# How to convert an array of number into ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to convert an array of numbers in sequence with gaps into an array of multiple ranges in Ruby.

Each range should be determined the gaps in the sequence:

```
[1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12]
```

The expected result would be:

```
[1-3, 5-6, 8-12]
```

I haven't been able to come up with any good ideas for tackling the problem. How can I go about solving this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: So I've tried to make a few edits to the question to make it better but staying in line with the answers allready provided.

Comment: I made a small library that does this: https://github.com/jaynetics/range_compressor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do as below using [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) :

```
a = [1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12]
prev = a[0]
p a.slice_before { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev2 + 1 != e
}.map{|b,*,c| c ? (b..c) : b }
# >> [1..3, 5..6, 8..12]
```

Comment: I +1d, but it will fail with an `ArgumentError` if there's a number that's not part of a range.

Comment: How about you include my version of the `map` call as an alternative and I delete my answer? No need for almost identical answers...

Comment: @MichaelKohl The point, you just noticed can be handled only using `?:` operator. So I did it. I didn't include your version, rather ruby tool I used :)

Comment: I just thought that destructuring plus a ternary may be a bit much for the OP. Anyway, here's the line from my now deleted answer: `.map { |es| es.length == 1 ? es.first : es.first..es.last }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,5,8,9,10,11,12]

b = [a.first-1] + (a.first..a.last).to_a - a + [a.last + 1]
  # => [0, 4, 6, 7, 13]
b.each_cons(2).with_object([]) {|(i,j), c| c << (i+1..j-1) if j > i+1}
  # => [1..3, 5..5, 8..12]
```

Alternatively,

```
b = [a.first] + ((a.first..a.last).to_a - a).flat_map {|e| [e-1,e+1]}+[a.last]
  # => [1, 3, 5, 5, 7, 6, 8, 12]
b.each_slice(2).map {|f,l| l >= f ? f..l : nil}.compact
  # => [1..3, 5..5, 8..12]
```

Note: `b.each_slice(2).to_a # => [[1, 3], [5, 5], [7, 6], [8, 12]]`

Comment: Is there a way we can do 
# => [1-3, 5, 8-12]
I came across with this documentation `slice_when` but this don't work in ruby 2.1.2 
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when

Comment: I find using `slice_when` is simpler (if you want the answer to include trivial ranges instead of integers it's an easy mod):

`Array#slice_when{|x, y| y > x + 1 }.map{|x, *, y| y.nil? ? x : (x..y)}`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
class Array
  def to_range_array
    res = [ Range.new(first,first) ]
    self[1..-1].sort.each{|item|
      if res.last.max == (item -1)
        res << Range.new(res.pop.min, item)
      else
        res << Range.new(item, item)
      end
    }
    res
  end
end

array =  [ 1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12 ]
p array.to_range_array #[1..3, 5..6, 8..12]
```

My assumptions:

- The ranges are based on the sorted array.
  `[ 9,10,11,12, 1,2,3,5,6,8]` should return the same result as `[ 1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12 ]`.
  Without the sort-command you get `[9..12, 1..3, 5..6, 8..8]`.
- Single values result in a one-value range (e.g. `8..8`)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12]

b = ((a.first..a.last+1).to_a - a).unshift(-(2**(0.size * 8 -2)))
  # => [-4611686018427387904, 4, 7, 13]
c = a.slice_before {|i| i > b.first ? b.shift : false}.to_a
  # => [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
c.map {|e| (e.first..e.last)}
  # => [1..3, 5..6, 8..12]
```

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer all the variants using `Enumerable#slice_before`, but here is an alternate solution using `Enumerable#each_cons`:

```
def array_to_ranges(arr)
  return [] if arr.empty?  
  seq, i = [[arr[0]]], 0  
  arr.each_cons(2) { |x,y| y-x == 1 ? seq[i] << y : seq[i+=1] = [y] }    
  seq.map { |range| range[0]..range[-1] }    
end
```

Note that if any singletons are present in `seq` it will turn those into ranges as well. For example, if `arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]` `array_to_ranges(arr)` returns `[1..3, 5..5, 7..8]`. An empty array is returned if the input is an empty array.